# RecyclerView inside of a GridView's item ruins the GridView's OnClickListener

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I have this disposition of layout:

[image]

which is a `GridView` with `RecyclerView`s inside of each item of the GridView.

I haven't found anywhere the solution since I think it never happened before. Not found in SO or Google Groups, for example.

So, the problem is, when I set a `RecyclerView`, the method `onItemClick` of the `GridView` doesn't get called, but if I don't set the `RecyclerView` it gets called. These are the two codes (one setting the `RecyclerView` and one hiding it):

**SETTING RECYCLERVIEW ON A `GRIDVIEW`'s ITEM**

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolderItem;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.item_mipeticion, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolderItem.palabra_TV = (CustomTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.palabra_TV);

            viewHolderItem.recyclerView = (RecyclerView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolderItem);
        } else {
            viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem)convertView.getTag();
        }

        MyItem item = items.get(position);
        String textRandom = item.getTexts().get(0);

        viewHolderItem.palabra_TV.setText(textRandom);
        ArrayList<Drawable> drawables = item.getDrawables();

        final RecyclerViewImagesAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerViewImagesAdapter(drawables, getActivity());
        viewHolderItem.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        viewHolderItem.recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return convertView;
    }
```

This makes the `onClick` not getting called for `GridView`

**AND THIS IS THE CODE HIDING IT**

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolderItem;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.item_mipeticion, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolderItem.palabra_TV = (CustomTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.palabra_TV);

            viewHolderItem.recyclerView = (RecyclerView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolderItem);
        } else {
            viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem)convertView.getTag();
        }

        MyItem item = items.get(position);
        String textRandom = item.getTexts().get(0);

        viewHolderItem.palabra_TV.setText(textRandom);
        ArrayList<Drawable> drawables = item.getDrawables();

        final RecyclerViewImagesAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerViewImagesAdapter(drawables, getActivity());
        viewHolderItem.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // just not setting the adapter and hidding it
        return convertView;
    }
```

What's wrong with this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

Rafael.

---

**EDIT:** What I've discovered that won't work

- Setting `android:clickable="false"` to the RecyclerView on the XML.
- Handle the `RecyclerView`'s click and calling the `parent.performClick()`
- Setting an `GestureDetector` as @Droidekas mentioned handles only the `RecyclerView`'s click, but not the whole item's click (so the `onItemClick` from `GridView`)

Comment: If the recyclerview should not be clickable you can set a attribute to your <layout>.xml  android:clickable="false". This will propagate the click event to your parent. Or you can do it in a not so good manner by calling in your childs click event: ((View)view.getParent()).performClick().

Comment: ``clickable="false"` not working nor `perfromClick();`

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand,You want all other actions apart from click to work on your recyclerview:

You need to differentiate between the Gestures. A job for the `GestureDetector` .So use the [GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)

```
final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                //perform parent view click
                return true;
            }
        });
```

You can then add a [RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html).

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                return gd.onTouchEvent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
```

This will make sure that all other touch events are handled by the `RecyclerView`

*PS* : Please make sure that itemview within the inner recyclerview does not have its own click event

Comment: Nope, this is not working. I try also to set it clickable = false and not working :(

Comment: have you added the `parentView.performclick` in the onSingleTapMethod?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in a comment of my question

Comment: Sorry, corrected. It just handles the `RecyclerView` click and not the item click

Comment: the parent of the item of a recycler view would be the recyclerview.You need to get the parent of the recyclerview

Comment: Something like `getParent().getParent().performClick()`

Comment: It's ok, it works, but only works when I click on the `RecyclerView`, nothing happens on the rest of the layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93873/discussion-between-droidekas-and-rafael-ruiz).